# Can someone help me understand why data is not being seeded to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I really need to deploy data to my heroku app but I don't understand why it's not working. I've read the documentation and I have seeded my database in the seeds.rb file like so:

```
user = User.create(band_name: "The Rubies", email: "therubies@gmail.com", user_name: "therubies1000", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")

MusicVideo.create([

  {song_title: "Ruby Gems"
    venue: "The Gypsy Lounge"
    location: "Boston"
    description: "First time in Boston"
    url_id: "http://vimeo.com/75032263"
    name: "hiphop"
    user: user},

    {song_title: "Ruby Blood Love"
    venue: "The Masquerade"
    location: "Atlanta"
    description: "5th circuit tour at the Masquerade"
    url_id: "http://vimeo.com/28020056"
    name: "alternative"
    user: user},

    {song_title: "Ruby vs. Python"
    venue: "Launch Academy"
    location: "Boston"
    description: "A love song about Ruby"
    url_id: "http://vimeo.com/67825649"
    name: "hiphop"
    user: user},

    {song_title: "Farewell Launch Academy"
    venue: "Los Locos Tavern"
    location: "New York City"
    description: "My heartfelt farewell balad for Launch Academy"
    url_id: "http://vimeo.com/60347451"
    name: "country"
    user: user},

    {song_title: "Solar Molecules"
    venue: "Miami Central"
    location: "Miami"
    description: "Our band's first single"
    url_id: "http://vimeo.com/61605196"
    name: "pop"
    user: user},

    {song_title: "Lovely Miss Ruby!"
    venue: "2120 nightclub"
    location: "Boston"
    description: "The song that made us famous"
    url_id: "http://vimeo.com/68269314"
    name: "pop"
    user: user},

    {song_title: "Lady Ruby vs. Lady Python"
    venue: "Longhorn Bar & Grill"
    location: "Austin"
    description: "Battle of the bands 2012"
    url_id: "http://vimeo.com/71137905"
    name: "rock"
    user: user},

    {song_title: "The Seductress: Rails"
    venue: "Igloo Bar"
    location: "Denver"
    description: "The crowd goes nuts at 2:14"
    url_id: "http://vimeo.com/70360517"
    name: "hiphop"
    user: user}

    ])
```

Then I've run the heroku rake db:migrate and then heroku rake db:seed as demonstrated in the rails app project website. I'd try to troubleshoot this but I don't know where to start or how to begin. These commands should work. I could really use some help with this.

----EDIT-----

When I use the two rake commands, I don't receive an error at all. I get this:

```
➜  musikfish git:(master) ✗ heroku run rake db:migrate
   Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.8472
➜  musikfish git:(master) ✗ heroku run rake db:seed
   Running `rake db:seed` attached to terminal... up, run.9065
```

The problem is that when I go to my heroku app, nothing is there.

```
musikfish git:(master) ✗ heroku logs
2014-04-29T01:27:43.662686+00:00 heroku[run.9065]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:seed`
2014-04-29T01:27:43.446432+00:00 heroku[run.9065]: State changed from starting to up
2014-04-29T01:27:48.599137+00:00 heroku[run.9065]: Process exited with status 0
2014-04-29T01:27:48.615271+00:00 heroku[run.9065]: State changed from up to complete
2014-04-29T01:27:59.356149+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=9198db15-ceb6-47d0-bf5c-9c0c8f86ed00 fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=13ms service=26ms status=304 bytes=963
2014-04-29T01:27:59.437007+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/vendor/modernizr-aee7c485b9900b5743cd0108ba6c4203.js host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=8fff456c-414b-44d5-9745-c287e21ae29f fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-04-29T01:27:59.447087+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-35b8d7e622749de25608aa28d2dab9bf.css host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=5b704bcd-11c5-445e-a3a4-3b5a9771b162 fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-04-29T01:27:59.452743+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-f22c7c9cfd4209f8467d10162777b447.js host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=99c37dd8-c9e7-414d-833c-b2355a0a7d78 fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-04-29T01:27:59.339867+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 76.19.195.114 at 2014-04-29 01:27:59 +0000
2014-04-29T01:27:59.339876+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 76.19.195.114 at 2014-04-29 01:27:59 +0000
2014-04-29T01:27:59.342081+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MusicVideosController#index as HTML
2014-04-29T01:27:59.350172+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered music_videos/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.2ms)
2014-04-29T01:27:59.350164+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered music_videos/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.2ms)
2014-04-29T01:27:59.342088+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MusicVideosController#index as HTML
2014-04-29T01:27:59.351185+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 4.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
2014-04-29T01:27:59.351191+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 4.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
2014-04-29T01:27:59.707282+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/concert-fa42c0b37cf58a39f5c756d58acc0cff.jpg host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=e62134aa-1020-4402-b507-e90f4cb2c2fa fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-04-29T01:28:01.827756+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users/sign_out host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=ba2049ed-925a-419f-8d8f-703025441667 fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=31ms status=302 bytes=1008
2014-04-29T01:28:01.933934+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=82444cc8-b75c-4f81-a5b7-a0c4dbebae00 fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=11ms status=302 bytes=1174
2014-04-29T01:28:02.019241+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/sign_in host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=ff98915d-2970-4369-81c4-b3335cf6fb50 fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=200 bytes=5117
2014-04-29T01:28:01.815374+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"6U9MH33BoyP3riIQVH9xRUG/jTGHDbDc9haqkb1wm+c="}
2014-04-29T01:28:01.812383+00:00 app[web.1]: Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 76.19.195.114 at 2014-04-29 01:28:01 +0000
2014-04-29T01:28:01.812441+00:00 app[web.1]: Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 76.19.195.114 at 2014-04-29 01:28:01 +0000
2014-04-29T01:28:01.836620+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://musikfish.herokuapp.com/
2014-04-29T01:28:01.815244+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
2014-04-29T01:28:01.815318+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
2014-04-29T01:28:01.836976+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 4.7ms)
2014-04-29T01:28:01.815409+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"6U9MH33BoyP3riIQVH9xRUG/jTGHDbDc9haqkb1wm+c="}
2014-04-29T01:28:01.836730+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://musikfish.herokuapp.com/
2014-04-29T01:28:01.837036+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 4.7ms)
2014-04-29T01:28:01.931057+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 76.19.195.114 at 2014-04-29 01:28:01 +0000
2014-04-29T01:28:01.931067+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 76.19.195.114 at 2014-04-29 01:28:01 +0000
2014-04-29T01:28:01.933233+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MusicVideosController#index as HTML
2014-04-29T01:28:01.933240+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MusicVideosController#index as HTML
2014-04-29T01:28:01.934294+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
2014-04-29T01:28:01.934300+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
2014-04-29T01:28:02.003346+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 76.19.195.114 at 2014-04-29 01:28:02 +0000
2014-04-29T01:28:02.003359+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 76.19.195.114 at 2014-04-29 01:28:02 +0000
2014-04-29T01:28:02.005391+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2014-04-29T01:28:02.005397+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2014-04-29T01:28:02.016010+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (8.1ms)
2014-04-29T01:28:02.016022+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (8.1ms)
2014-04-29T01:28:02.016885+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 9.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-04-29T01:28:02.016891+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 9.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-04-29T01:28:02.165810+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/record-b8785487ad26187346eb4a4f3ca44b8e.jpg host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=761b5080-013c-4308-8073-6ae64ee63fe5 fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-04-29T01:28:24.575301+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users/sign_in host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=95ef1998-d961-4783-8685-d7d463c04cd8 fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=134ms status=200 bytes=5158
2014-04-29T01:28:24.444910+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 76.19.195.114 at 2014-04-29 01:28:24 +0000
2014-04-29T01:28:24.450353+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-04-29T01:28:24.450395+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-04-29T01:28:24.450480+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8oU2ObllOpGkDy+clk2mfnxi9y/oY/JpEWJAGVVEmNA=", "user"=>{"user_name"=>"therubies1000", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign In!"}
2014-04-29T01:28:24.456080+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 5ms
2014-04-29T01:28:24.457165+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2014-04-29T01:28:24.457172+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2014-04-29T01:28:24.457213+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8oU2ObllOpGkDy+clk2mfnxi9y/oY/JpEWJAGVVEmNA=", "user"=>{"user_name"=>"therubies1000", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign In!"}
2014-04-29T01:28:24.450529+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8oU2ObllOpGkDy+clk2mfnxi9y/oY/JpEWJAGVVEmNA=", "user"=>{"user_name"=>"therubies1000", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign In!"}
2014-04-29T01:28:24.456071+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 5ms
2014-04-29T01:28:24.457231+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8oU2ObllOpGkDy+clk2mfnxi9y/oY/JpEWJAGVVEmNA=", "user"=>{"user_name"=>"therubies1000", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign In!"}
2014-04-29T01:28:24.570577+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (9.5ms)
2014-04-29T01:28:24.570588+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (9.5ms)
2014-04-29T01:28:24.571495+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 114ms (Views: 11.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-04-29T01:28:24.571501+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 114ms (Views: 11.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-04-29T01:28:24.444975+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 76.19.195.114 at 2014-04-29 01:28:24 +0000
2014-04-29T01:28:24.685158+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-f22c7c9cfd4209f8467d10162777b447.js host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=88423114-72bc-49e8-bb7d-cf5b19fc1908 fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-04-29T01:28:24.868171+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/vendor/modernizr-aee7c485b9900b5743cd0108ba6c4203.js host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=5724d3e6-9603-4b84-84fb-3ba5c696c74f fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=118ms service=41ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-04-29T01:31:54.118937+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users/sign_in host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=a92e7853-43a3-48b5-9f42-6e55beaf1be2 fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=173ms status=200 bytes=5158
2014-04-29T01:31:53.955209+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 76.19.195.114 at 2014-04-29 01:31:53 +0000
2014-04-29T01:31:53.957652+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-04-29T01:31:53.957659+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-04-29T01:31:53.957698+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8oU2ObllOpGkDy+clk2mfnxi9y/oY/JpEWJAGVVEmNA=", "user"=>{"user_name"=>"therubies1000", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign In!"}
2014-04-29T01:31:53.957720+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8oU2ObllOpGkDy+clk2mfnxi9y/oY/JpEWJAGVVEmNA=", "user"=>{"user_name"=>"therubies1000", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign In!"}
2014-04-29T01:31:53.968990+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 11ms
2014-04-29T01:31:53.969002+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 11ms
2014-04-29T01:31:53.971927+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2014-04-29T01:31:53.955199+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 76.19.195.114 at 2014-04-29 01:31:53 +0000
2014-04-29T01:31:53.971933+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2014-04-29T01:31:53.971976+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8oU2ObllOpGkDy+clk2mfnxi9y/oY/JpEWJAGVVEmNA=", "user"=>{"user_name"=>"therubies1000", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign In!"}
2014-04-29T01:31:53.971991+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8oU2ObllOpGkDy+clk2mfnxi9y/oY/JpEWJAGVVEmNA=", "user"=>{"user_name"=>"therubies1000", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign In!"}
2014-04-29T01:31:54.117705+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.9ms)
2014-04-29T01:31:54.117717+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.9ms)
2014-04-29T01:31:54.118464+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 146ms (Views: 7.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-04-29T01:31:54.118470+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 146ms (Views: 7.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-04-29T01:31:54.237788+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-35b8d7e622749de25608aa28d2dab9bf.css host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=77e5536c-f9af-4285-a236-a011c1355b81 fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-04-29T01:31:54.243275+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-f22c7c9cfd4209f8467d10162777b447.js host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=8ca4ebaf-739d-4e4a-901b-e616e2b7033b fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=11ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-04-29T01:31:54.264123+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/vendor/modernizr-aee7c485b9900b5743cd0108ba6c4203.js host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=f2a2d4e9-4163-425d-b26b-5255a6a1f5fe fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-04-29T01:31:54.772855+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/record-b8785487ad26187346eb4a4f3ca44b8e.jpg host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=d103b167-2ed5-4667-874f-679e3d07b859 fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-04-29T01:32:03.174817+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=cd1eb130-8cf7-453a-982f-b7a74ccafe3e fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=11ms service=16ms status=302 bytes=1226
2014-04-29T01:32:03.158631+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MusicVideosController#index as HTML
2014-04-29T01:32:03.158689+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MusicVideosController#index as HTML
2014-04-29T01:32:03.159895+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
2014-04-29T01:32:03.159937+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
2014-04-29T01:32:03.156335+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 76.19.195.114 at 2014-04-29 01:32:03 +0000
2014-04-29T01:32:03.156448+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 76.19.195.114 at 2014-04-29 01:32:03 +0000
2014-04-29T01:32:03.570966+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/sign_in host=musikfish.herokuapp.com request_id=0bcfa714-0019-4860-aa40-c18140690458 fwd="76.19.195.114" dyno=web.1 connect=121ms service=165ms status=200 bytes=5117
2014-04-29T01:32:03.511737+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 76.19.195.114 at 2014-04-29 01:32:03 +0000
2014-04-29T01:32:03.511725+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 76.19.195.114 at 2014-04-29 01:32:03 +0000
2014-04-29T01:32:03.514596+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2014-04-29T01:32:03.527802+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 10.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-04-29T01:32:03.527809+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 10.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-04-29T01:32:03.514590+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2014-04-29T01:32:03.527020+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (9.6ms)
2014-04-29T01:32:03.527010+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (9.6ms)
```

Comment: show me log or server log. what error does it throw?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply Jiten K. I made an edit that showed what I got, but I don't get an error at all. Nothing shows up in my heroku app though.

Comment: you need to past this on your command prompt to see heroku logs -->
heroku logs -n 200

Comment: Ok but just to warn you, its really long and ugly though cuz I tried some fixes of my own and ran the commands again at least twice. I don't know if I could start all over again for a cleaner log, but I'll try post it.

Comment: look up heroku logs using papertrail. it is free on heroku and you can view logs nicely on browser real time

Comment: damn I messed up ill get it right let me look into this papertrail. I'm really knew to heroku and programming in general sorry my friend. I'm trying to make this easy.

Comment: Another noob question, how can I indent multiple lines of code on stackoverflow

Comment: use quote for indentation. like this 'im wrapper around with quote'

Answer (score 0):

Have you successfully seeded a database locally?

You can also try putting `puts` lines in your seed file to ensure that the code is being run. (IE, after MusicVideo.create, say `puts "Music Videos created!"`, which will be written to your console when running `rake db:seed`)

My hunch is that your models are failing validation; perhaps try using `create!` instead of `create` to see if an error is thrown.

Comment: Hey gdpelican, I have successfully loaded data in locally, but I don't know why the production database won't populate. If it was a matter of validations failing, the local seed population wouldn't have worked right?